# How to input an operator (+ - / *) as a string and change it so that it can be used as an operator? [c++]

Tags: c++

I'm making a basic calculator but I don't want to use a case statement to go through every possible outcome for every operator that could be entered. Instead I would like the user to input "x + y" and then be able to isolate the "+" operator and use it in my code. So then the operator could just be assigned to a variable and I can have one line of code such as:

```
answer = x operator y;
```

Comment: What you need is a parser ... but that's a whole discussion on its own. For C++, the most usual choice might be the flex/bison combination. Although with flex alone you can already go quite far.

Comment: Or, of course, writing your own parser; if the program is for learning purposes (which a basic calculator most probably is), that's probably the best alternative.